# Validating Contact Numbers using JQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate whether user is entering mobile number correctly.
For this I have written the following regex which seems to be buggy.
Mobile number can **Optionally** start with **+** can have  **Optional spaces, round brackets, hyphens ( - )**.
It cannot contain any **alphabets** or **any other character**.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("mobileNumber", function(value,element) {
            return this.optional(element) ||  /(?:([+]))?[0-9]*/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid Contact Number");
```

Following inputs should match,

> +1-222
>
> (+1) 222
>
> +1222
>
> 2222
>
> 02-222

But these shouldn't match.

> 1+222
>
> AAA
>
> AA12
>
> 2.2.2

How should I write the regex for above criteria?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look [here][1]. This may be helpful


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/123681/2266001

Comment: What's wrong with the Mobile Phone Number rules already built into this plugin's `additional-methods.js` file?  See:  http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: I didn't know about that such rule exists.. does it satisfy the above criteria ?

Comment: Just take a peek to find out:  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js

Comment: Thnxx.. I saw it..But US & UK formats wont suite me.. It's little more strict than I currently need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^(\+|\(\+)?\d+(\-|\)|\s)+?\d+
```

See it working here: http://regexr.com?34sm1

Comment: Thanks so much.. it's indeed covering all the cases I need.. =]

Answer (score 0):

```
// true
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('+1-222');
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('(+1)222');
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('+1222');
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('01-2222');
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('86-2222');
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('2222');

// false
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('1+2342');
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('+123-222');
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('AAA');
/^(\+[0-9]{1,2}\-|\(\+[0-9]{1,2}\)|\+[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{2}\-|)[0-9]+$/.test('6786-2342');
```